# Clearance - different URLs for text & html confirmation emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

I am using clearance for authorization and am running into an issue where the text and html email confirmations that go out to potential new users have different confirmation urls - the text one works and the html one leads to a routing error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/confirm.35"
```

What have I configured incorrectly? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

**Here are both emails**

```
 ----==_mimepart_59d4f36d414c_6463fe23fe154401369b
    Content-Type: text/plain;
     charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    Please click below to confirm your new account.

    http://localhost:3000/users/35/password/edit?token=d8dadce7863b92fdf27f7c7b474943c209173c6e

    If you didn't request this, ignore this email.

    ----==_mimepart_59d4f36d414c_6463fe23fe154401369b
    Content-Type: text/html;
     charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    <p>Please click below to confirm your new account.</p>

    <p>
      <a href="http://localhost:3000/confirm.35?token=d8dadce7863b92fdf27f7c7b474943c209173c6e">Confirm account</a>
    </p>

    <p>If you didn't request this, ignore this email.</p>

    ----==_mimepart_59d4f36d414c_6463fe23fe154401369b--
```

Comment: Clearance does not have built in account confirmation emails. Did you add a mailer for this? What does your plain text view look like? How about the HTML view?

Answer (score 0):

My mailers had different code for txt vs html versions. I incorrectly thought Clearance had built in account confirmation emails. Thanks!